# NSNumber causing a SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnumber

I have a strange problem (strange if you ask me). Im using a `NSNumber` object to store a number (doh). When I try to "modify" it it crashes my application. The code I'm using looks like this:

```
if ([frequency intValue] > 19999)
    return;
frequency = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([frequency intValue] + 1)]; //I think this line is causing me the problem
[freqLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Hz", [frequency intValue]]];
```

Where is frequency the `NSNumber` and freqLabel my label to which I write the value every time this gets called. 
Why is this incorrect? It works when I call it for the first time. Is it that `NSNumber numberWithInt` always returns a new object which I'm trying to assign to frequency? 
How do I fix this? Whats the correct way to change a `NSNumber`'s value?

Sorry for my bad english (if there are any mistakes).

EDIT:
The error log looks like this:

```
[__NSCFType intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73430e0
2012-05-09 16:39:28.064 MyApp[31939:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73430e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x17a6022 0x28afcd6 0x17a7cbd 0x170ced0 0x170ccb2 0x4821 0x17a7e99 0x49d14e 0x49d0e6 0x543ade 0x543fa7 0x543266 0x4c23c0 0x4c25e6 0x4a8dc4 0x49c634 0x2e49ef5 0x177a195 0x16deff2 0x16dd8da 0x16dcd84 0x16dcc9b 0x2e487d8 0x2e4888a 0x49a626 0x1cca 0x1c15)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

But it doesn't always show this error. Sometimes it causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Should I store my variable in a temporary `NSNumber`?

Comment: Could you add `NSLog(@"%@", frequency);` before the `if` and tell us what gets printed?

Comment: @Zepplock I've edited the post. dasblinkenlight it prints the normal value.

Comment: Can you please show us how you're declaring the ivar and the line you 're first assigning a value to it?

Comment: frequency gets `[[alloc] init]`-ed in `viewDidLoad`. I managed to solve this issue. `frequency` is a class variable and a `@property`. Im synthesizing it like this `@synthesize frequency = frequency`. If I use `self.frequency` instead of just `frequency` it works. What was I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just alloc/init something once and then you have a lifelong reference to that type.  When you assign frequency to numberWithInt, then you are **overwriting** the previous alloc/init value with an *autorelease* value (which will be released later and cause the exact behavior you are describing).  The reason it works with self.frequency is because your property is set as a retain property, so it automatically retains the autorelease value.  Add a retain to your numberWithInt line and it will be fine (or do what you are doing now with self.frequency).

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I finally understand this `retain` thingie. Now I finally know why I'm always putting `(nonatomic, retain)` when declaring objects. Before it was just "because tutorials say so". Im still young and learning :)

Comment: @Majster With ARC, the retain keyword becomes largely irrelevant.

Comment: Yes I agree. But I still prefer myself as the "garbage collector". I know I may not be as efficient as ARC but at least I know (or think to know) what I'm doing with memory.

Comment: Careful with your terms.  ARC is not the same as garbage collection.  It is about halfway between completely manual and garbage collection.  Watch out though, I wouldn't be surprised if Apple phased out the manual way in favor of ARC-only one day.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing this instead

```
int myNumber = ([frequency intValue] + 1);
frequency = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `numberWithInt:` does indeed return a new object. You're probably not retaining this object. Just properly retain `frequency` when assigning it a new `NSNumber`. Without context, I'm not sure the best way to accomplish this, but one way is to make `frequency` a property of your object and using the accessor method.

Comment: I get the idea, but could you try explaining it more simply please? How should I properly retain `frequency`? `frequency` is my class variable and my property. Im synthesizing it like this `@synthesize frequency = frequency`. Is this also wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you've already initialized and assigned some value prior to NSNumber, like you have it inside an array for example.

Basically NSNumber objects are immutable, so changing their value is not possible anyway.
You can do it this workaround if you use it inside an array:

```
NSMutableArray *myOldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
myOldInt = 3;
myOldArray[4] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myOldInt]; // for example

NSMutableArray *myNewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
myInt = myOldInt+2; 

NSMutableArray *row = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:myOldArray[1],myOldArray[2],myOldArray[3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt],[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt2],nil];

[myNewArray addObject:row];
```